# Embed Youtube/Vimeo videos into email template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, youtube, vimeo

I need to embed a video (youtube and vimeo) into my email template.I have tried below mentioned 2 methods.But those are not working.Could you tell me why ? Thanks in advance.

**Method 1 :**

```
 <video id="SomeID" name="media" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RFinNxS5KN4"></video>
```

**Method 2 :**

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RFinNxS5KN4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: I think this depends on the email client the person is using. you would have to make sure the email is marked as HTML format and not text. I suspect most (if not all) prevent these videos from loading for security purposes and the best you can do is a hyprerlink to the video itself.

Comment: @br4d email client is `Gmail`.You mean without embedding it ?

Comment: Correct. iframes in email would be disastrous and html5 video tags probably follow suit. Could you imagine getting a spam mail with a porn video directly embedded into it? Ughhh. Just hyperlink it with a fancy image or something

Comment: @br4d Yes,you're right.I'll get the thumbnail of the video and then put that with the video url as you mentioned.Thanks a lot.Can you put your answer as the solution ? Then I can close this post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simpler answer is: you cant embed them into emails.

While HTML enabled email clients allow valid HTML, they will filter out embed tags and HTML5 video links as a security concern. If they were enabled it would create a whole new world for spammers of referral links and such.

A good workaround would be to just hyperlink to the video instead (or to a page on your site that has them embedded) using a nicely crafted image. Make sure the email header specifies HTML and not text if you do this.